# Connect to a database located on phpmyadmin from python

Tags: python, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm looking to connect to a database via python.
The database is on phpmyadmin.

I read the section "variable" on phpmyadmin and I saw that the hostname is "atexo-sourcing-prod-01.local-trust.com".

Unfortunately, when I try to connect with this python code and with the same login and password that I use to connect to phpmyadmnin:

```
try:
conn = mariadb.connect(
    user="mylogin",
    password="my_password",
    host="atexo-sourcing-prod-01.local-trust.com",
    port=3306,
    database="atexo_prod_sourcing_db")

except mariadb.Error as e:
    print(f"Error connecting to MariaDB Platform: {e}")
```

I have an error, saying

> Can't connect to server on 'atexo-sourcing-prod-01.local-trust.com'
> (10061)

(I think it's not a problem of hostname, because when I put a random name, I have an other error).

Any idea to fix this?

Comment: If your code is going to be on the same server, then leave the hostname out, or try **localhost**

Comment: What is the hostname that's defined in your phpMyAdmin configuration file, `config.inc.php`? The value that shows in the variable view is probably showing the machine's hostname, which may not be exactly what you need to connect to.